# represent an index inside a list as x,y in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a list which contains 1000 integers. The 1000 integers represent 20X50 elements of dimensional array which I read from a file into the list.

I need to walk through the list with an indicator in order to find close elements to each other. I want that my indicator will be represented not only by a simple index i, but as a two indices x,y so I can know where is my indicator along the list.

I tried to reshape the list like that:

```
data = np.array( l )
shape = ( 20, 50 )
data.reshape( shape )
```

but I don't know how to access the data array.

Update: Is there any way to find the indices of x, y for an integers that are smaller than NUM(let's say NUM=12)

Comment: Could you please provide a shortened sample list? What do you mean by '20x50' elements? Does your list contain 20 sublists with 50 elements each?

Comment: Can you do `data.shape` first please and give us the result ?

Comment: @albert The list is a very simple list. Not list inside list or other manipulations with lists. A list like a list of names but with numbers

Comment: I try to find inside an array of 4 elements (2X2) that it's elements are lower than 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) of `numpy.reshape` , it returns a new array object with the new shape specified by the parameters (given that, with the new shape, the amount of elements in the array remain unchanged) , without changing the shape of the original object, so when you are calling the `data.reshape()`  function you should also assign it back to data for it to reflect in data.

Example -

```
data = data.reshape( shape )  # where shape = (20,50)
```

Also, another way to change the shape, is to directly assign the new `shape` to the `data.shape` property.

Example -

```
shape = (20,50)
data.shape = shape # where shape is the new shape
```

Comment: Also, I have updated the answer with another easy way to change the shape, just for FYI.

Comment: Is there any way to find the indices of x, y for the data if for example I need to find all the elements that are smaller than 12?

Comment: Yes, you can use the function `numpy.where` as - `numpy.where(data < 12)` , it will return a list of lists , where inner list is row index and column index , example - [[0,0],[1,0]] , etc. Try it out yourself

Comment: data_indices=list()
    data_indices = np.where(data >= obj_value_min and data<=obj_value_max)
    print(data_indices)

The above returns an error: 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81183/discussion-between-axcelenator-and-anand-s-kumar).